# Working with Objective-C blocks with Swift

Tags: objective-c, closures, swift

I'm having trouble using the Objective-C Firebase framework in a new Swift project.  I'm coming from mostly a C# background so the Swift closure syntax isn't that clear yet.

Here's how the code work in Objective-C with f being the Firebase object

```
[f observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", snapshot.name, snapshot.value);
}];
```

XCode auto suggests this syntax, and I have yet to find a working solution.

```
f.observeEventType(FEventTypeValue, withBlock: ((FDataSnapshot!) -> Void)?)
```

I'd like assign the FDataSnapshot data to a variable as the Objective-C example is doing.  Thanks

Comment: Closures in Swift are like anonymous methods in C#. For example, `Action<T>` translates to `(T) -> Void` and `Func<TArg, TResult>` becomes `(TArg) -> TResult`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the Swift equivalent:

```
f.observeEventType(FEventTypeValue, withBlock: {
    snapshot in
    println("\(snapshot.name) -> \(snapshot.value)")
})
```

The key here is the `in` keyword to assign arguments to the closure to variables

Comment: I was wondering if you can take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/acegreen/05282d20eb45de8d30d5

Answer (score 4):

To throw in implied names and tail closures, you can use:

```
f.observeEventType(FEventTypeValue) {
    println("\($0.name) -> \($0.value)")
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it need the last parameter name, though?

Comment: No, it uses implied naming and typing as long as there's a single trailing block and you put the '{' on the same line as the ')'

Comment: How does it know the name of the `withBlock:` parameter, though? I thought named parameters still needed to be named. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: It's somewhere in the iTunes book.  Look through the section on closures, I think they call it tail closures.

Comment: That's great. I knew about trailing closures before, but I didn't quite grasp it. Thanks for that!

Comment: Does this trailing closure work for any ObjC method that end with a `withBlock:` argument?

Comment: @AlexWayne It works for any function that ends with a closure argument, the names and types are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Swift blocks are interchangeable with Objective-C blocks, so it ought to be something like:

```
f.observeEventType(FEventTypeValue, withBlock: { 
    snapshot in 
    println("\(snapshot.name) -> \(snapshot.value)")
})
```