# How can i access objective c block in a swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift, callback

I can access objective c class in swift project through bridging header. But how can i implement that object c class callback method.

Example : i have an callback decleare in ClassObjectiveC

```
typedef void(^PlayCompleteCallBack)(BOOL playSuccess, NSString *processfileName);
@property (nonatomic, copy)   PlayCompleteCallBack playCompleteCallBack;
```

In objective c

I can access like this

```
ClassObjectiveC *obj = [[ClassObjectiveC alloc]init];

[obj setPlayCompleteCallBack:^(BOOL playSuccess, NSString *processfileName){

 }];
```

> But in Swift when i want to access this callback how can i implement this. thanks

Comment: Try typing with obj Xcode will suggest you

Comment: i have to use this in swift file. actually it is in a framework which i have to access in swift

Comment: Yes, and i can call other methods. but can not listen to the callback. Didi not get the syntex

Comment: No i already did this it is not working

Comment: Maybe you can try it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168612/working-with-objective-c-blocks-with-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `playCompleteCallBack` this way.

```
let yourObject = ClassObjectiveC()
yourObject.playCompleteCallBack = { (success, name) in
    //Access success and name here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
 obj.playCompleteCallBack = {(_ playSuccess: Bool, _ processfileName: String) -> Void in
         //Your code
     }
```